# install individual stack

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to install individual stack according to guides at link [ROS installation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu)

I use this line:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping
```

I had already installed Desktop-Full Install and want to install other stacks individually. Specifically, stacks I tried to install:
robotino, robotino_kinect, simple_grasping and a few others but all failed

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-robotino
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-simple-grapsping
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-robotino-kinect
```

errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-robotino
```

What might be wrong here?? did I use the commands incorrectly??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45222/install-individual-stack/) by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2012-10-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-10-06**:
You could try to install via svn(URL can be found in the wiki) or add the url of the source code to the apt-get install command...

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-10-06**:
@Flowers: I've just turned to use Ubuntu for 2 weeks and not sure what svn is. Could you tell me clearer? some code lines for example

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-10-07**:
I think ipso is right! I tried to install another stack with: apt-cache search ros-fuerte-pr2-simulator and it worked so smoothly

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-08**:
apt-cache gives you information about packages. For information on svn (subversion), google will probably be helpful.

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-10-12**:
@Flowers: thanks for you help!! actually, I finally did it with svn for packages without debian files. simply checkout from svn to download the source files and build it with ccmake or rosmake. That's what I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To use svn, first make sure it is installed:
sudo apt-get install subversion libapache2-svn
then by:
svn checkout http://svn.openrobotino.org/robotino-ros-pkg/trunk/robotino /home/ros_workspace/robotino
you can download the package(of course you can replace /home/... by any path you want to install the package to, but make sure the path is in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and ROS_WORKSPACE)..

afterwards you have the files in your folder and can run rosmake robotino...

---

Originally posted by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) with karma: 342 on 2012-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would use the excellent `rosws` tool.  If you have followed the Fuerte installation instructions, you should already have it.  This is the ideal way to find packages that aren't available through apt-get.

If not, use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall
```

You can then do the following:

```
# Initialize a workspace
rosws init ~/robotino_testing

# Source that workspace
cd ~/robotino_testing && source ./setup.bash

# Merge your OS install
rosws merge /opt/ros/fuerte

# Find the robotino repository and merge it locally
roslocate info robotino | rosws merge -
roslocate info robotino_kinect | rosws merge -
roslocate info simple_grasping | rosws merge -

# Update your workspace
rosws update
```

Now you can just `rosmake` the packages that you are interested in using.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-10-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-08**:
[relevant wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays).

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-10-08**:
I did not indicate to manage the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and ROS_WORKSPACE by hand, it is part of the first tutorials to create a ROS_WORKSPACE...it was just additional information because tools like roscd won't find any package which is not part of the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH ^^

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-10-09**:
@Flowers, sorry! You are correct, and I have modified my answer.